# Pass static method and model class via contructor paramters

Tags: flutter

I have extracted the `DropdownSearch<String>` widget and created a independent custom widget extending the features of `DropdownSearch<String>`. I have done this to reduce code size and encapsulate certain functionality.

On an average a single form contains 5-6 DropdownSearch widgets. Their are multiple such forms.

I am populating the items on the widget via API call using Dio package. I have created model and serializer using built_value packages.

My question is how do I pass the `fromJson` static method and the model class via const constructor parameters

Code :

```
import 'package:dio/dio.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:dropdown_search/dropdown_search.dart';
import 'package:reference_wrapper/reference_wrapper.dart';

class DropDownSearch extends StatefulWidget {
  final Ref<String> itemSelected;
  final String url;
  final String label;
  const DropDownSearch({
    required this.itemSelected,
    required this.url,
    required this.label,
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<DropDownSearch> createState() => _DropDownSearchState();
}

class _DropDownSearchState extends State<DropDownSearch> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DropdownSearch<String>(
      mode: Mode.MENU,
      showSelectedItems: true,
      showSearchBox: true,
      showAsSuffixIcons: true,
      dropdownSearchDecoration: InputDecoration(
        label: Text(widget.label),
        focusColor: Colors.blue,
        border: const OutlineInputBorder(
          borderSide: BorderSide(
            style: BorderStyle.solid,
          ),
        ),
      ),
      validator: (value) {
        if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
          return 'Please select ${widget.label}';
        }
        return null;
      },
      onFind: (text) async {
        var response = await Dio().get(
          widget.url,
        );
        if (response.statusCode != 200) {}
        final ipcStatusList = IpcStatusList.fromJson(response.data); //How to pass this static method as parameter
        return ipcStatusList.ipcStatus.toList(); //How to pass this as parameter
      },
      onChanged: (value) => setState(
        () {
          widget.itemSelected.ref = value ?? '';
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can make a final variable in your "DropDownSearch" which is the same type of toJson. And when using this Class, pass your static variable.

Comment: The problem with is approach is that their are at-least 47 different model class and similar number of toJson static method that I can currently count of (as their are 47 API currently). The scope will increase in future as the system grows to cover more aspect of manufacturing process increasing number of API in future (thus increasing model class and toJson static methods).